# Kendo grid Export to Excel (Open File insted of Save)

Tags: jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

I am using Kendo Grid in my application and when I am doing Export to Excel, Open file option is not there, only Save and Cancel options are available. I have checked in both IE11 and Chrome.Same result in both browsers.

As per my observation, Open file option is not coming for the files that are generated using telerik kendo controls like Excel, PDF, CSV files.

Here,my requirement is, Open file option should come along with SAVE and CANCEL options in file download prompt.

Any reply on this post is highly appreciated as this is critical requirement for me.

Thanks,
Lavanya.

Comment: Is there anyway when exporting to have the file open option instead of prompting to save?

Comment: Do you need to save the file to a specific location?